# After loading articles, the player script does not work?

Tags: ajax

my content is loaded using ajax and in some articles I use the jwplayer player, but after the articles are loaded, the player script does not work. Here is the player output code itself

```
    <div id='38'></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var playerInstance = jwplayer("38");
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrBLHH3WZ5M",
        width: "100%",
           height: "100%"
    });
    </script>

Here is a script for loading articles

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var $container = $('#masonry');
            
            $container.infinitescroll({
                navSelector : '#navigation',
                nextSelector : '#navigation #navigation-next a',
                itemSelector : '.item',
                maxPage       :5,
 loading: {
     
            msgText: '<?php _e('Loading', 'prpin') ?>',
            finishedMsg: '<?php _e('All items loaded', 'prpin') ?>',
            img: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/loading.gif', 
            
    }
},
            
// запускаем Masonry как обратный вызов
            function(newElements) {
// скрываем новые элементы во время загрузки
                var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
                    opacity: 0});           
// убедитесь, что изображения загружаются перед добавлением в макет кладки
                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
                    // показать элементы, теперь они готовы
$newElems.animate({
                        opacity: 1});
                    $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
                    
                    
                });
                onAfterLoaded($newElems);
        }
            );
            
    });
```

Please help me solve this problem, for a long time I can not find a solution

Comment: "Does not work" how exactly?  What specifically is failing?

Comment: After scrolling, the video does not show. 
here you can see in the workbot http://wido.wp-style.ru/